# How to send index to slot with a QMenu

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qcombobox, qmenu

I am trying to get [QComboBox-like behavior](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#activated) using a `QPushButton` that brings up a `QMenu`. Namely, when an action is selected, I want to connect to a slot, and for the slot to print out the index of the selected item. Relevant class definition:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class PushIt(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)  
        menBut=self.makeQMenuButton()
        self.show()        

    def makeQMenuButton(self):
        button=QtGui.QPushButton("Men...you!", self)           
        pushMenu=QtGui.QMenu(button)
        #Set up each element of menu
        menBut1=pushMenu.addAction("Select me!")
        menBut2=pushMenu.addAction("Don't select me!")
        #What to do when each one is activated
        menBut1.activated[int].connect(self.menButSlot)
        menBut2.activated[int].connect(self.menButSlot) 
        button.setMenu(pushMenu)       
        return button

    @QtCore.Slot(int)
    def menButSlot(self, menDat):
        print "Menu button ", menDat
```

It *sort of* works. When I push button 1, for instance, it returns:

```
Menu button -3
```

Which is close to what I would get using a combobox, except the counting is seeming to start with -3 instead of 0. I assumed it would start with 0, so I think I am not accessing an index at all, but am toying with powers I do not understand.

I am using PySide within iPython/Anaconda in Windows 7.

Comment: `activated` signal is deprecated and shouldn't be used in new code. Use `triggered` instead (but it doesn't have int argument). You can use `QSignalMapper` to pass additional value to a slot. Alternatively, you can use `QAction::setData` to attach data to each action; you can get chosen action in the slot using `self.sender()` and use `data()` to get data back.

Comment: @Pavel interesting: I assume it is not deprecated for QCombobox?

Comment: `QCombobox::activated` is not deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to comment by Pavel Strakhov, the `QMenu.activated` signal is deprecated. He suggested the use of `QSignalMapper` to send an index to a slot. This worked great, as follows:

```
class PushIt(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)  
        menBut=self.makeQMenuButton()
        self.show()        

    def makeQMenuButton(self):
        button=QtGui.QPushButton("Men...you!", self)           
        #Set up qmenu and its items
        pushMenu=QtGui.QMenu(button)
        menBut1=pushMenu.addAction("Select me!")
        menBut2=pushMenu.addAction("Don't select me!")
        button.setMenu(pushMenu)   

        #set up mapping to create your own indexing scheme
        menuMapping=QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)
        menuMapping.setMapping(menBut1, 0)
        menuMapping.setMapping(menBut2, 1)

        menBut1.triggered.connect(menuMapping.map)
        menBut2.triggered.connect(menuMapping.map)
        menuMapping.mapped[int].connect(self.menButSlot) 

        return button

    @QtCore.Slot(int)
    def menButSlot(self, menDat):
        print "Home-grown triggered index:", menDat
```

This works exactly as I was hoping (though I am still curious about the strange negative values I was receiving for `activated`).

Comment: Note I am timid to accept my own answer, but it seems to work. If I don't hear any protests, I'll check it as the accepted answer tomorrow. Credit should go to Pavel, so go up there and upvote his comment that inspired this solution. :)